# Почему atoi возвращает двузначное значение?

Tags: c++, c

Я вытаскивал предпоследнюю цифру числа с плавающей запятой, и чтобы получить такую цифру , я записал float-число в массив через `sprintf`, и вытащил предпоследнюю цифру , и перевел через `atoi`. Но записалось двузначное число, поэтому пришлось делать `div 10`. Почему atoi взял лишнюю цифру справа, а не перевел лишь одну цифру, а две.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        x = x + 0.99;
        memset(myString, 0, 30);
        t = tan(2.0 * x);
        sprintf(myString, "%f", t);

        f_x[i] = atoi(&myString[strlen(myString) - 2])/10; // точность округления 8 знаков и был взят предпоследний
        //f_x[i] = myString[strlen(myString) - 2]-'0'; еще способ
    }
```

Comment: Так а с чего вы взяли, что результат должен быть однозначным? Вы скормили `atoi` запись двузначного числа. Его и получили. Что такое "лишняя цифра справа"? Почему вдруг `atoi` должен был считать ее "лишней"?

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` работает со строкой, а не с символом.

```
int atoi(const char *str)
```

Строка начинается с указанного адреса и завершается нулевым символом
Так что всё, как прописано.

Можно взять именно символ  `myString[strlen(myString) - 2]`, и отнять от него код нуля `0x30` - вот и будет нужное значение.

Comment: ,а можно ли указать диапозон для atoi ?

Comment: Можно скопировать часть строки в новую (`strncpy`) и применить atoi. Для одного символа это делать нелепо.